# RubyGems fails after upgrade to Fedora 37 with error in psych-4.0.4

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fedora

Upgraded from Fedora 35 to 37. Any `gem` operation gives an error while loading `psych-4.0.4`:

```
# sudo gem list
<internal:/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': libruby.so.3.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/lib64/gems/ruby/stringio-3.0.4/stringio.so (LoadError)
    from <internal:/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/psych-4.0.4/lib/psych/nodes/node.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/psych-4.0.4/lib/psych/nodes.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/psych-4.0.4/lib/psych/nodes.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/ruby/psych.rb:15:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/share/ruby/psych.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:610:in `load_yaml'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/config_file.rb:346:in `load_file'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/config_file.rb:189:in `initialize'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:71:in `new'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:71:in `do_configuration'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

The referenced file exists:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib64/gems/ruby/stringio-3.0.4/stringio.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 187824 Jan  8 09:12 /usr/lib64/gems/ruby/stringio-3.0.4/stringio.so
```

However, it is missing a dependency on Ruby 3.0:

```
# ldd /usr/lib64/gems/ruby/stringio-3.0.4/stringio.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff3632d000)
    libruby.so.3.0 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fef11fa3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fef121ad000)
```

This makes sense because the Fedora-managed Ruby is 3.1:

```
# dnf list installed ruby
Installed Packages
ruby.x86_64                       3.1.3-173.fc37                        @updates
# ls -l /lib64/libruby*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Dec  8 12:08 /lib64/libruby.so -> libruby.so.3.1.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Dec  8 12:08 /lib64/libruby.so.3.1 -> libruby.so.3.1.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3979136 Dec  8 12:08 /lib64/libruby.so.3.1.3
```

Trying to reinstall rubygems with `sudo dnf reinstall rubygems` doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `rm -rf /usr/share/gems/ /usr/share/ruby*` and then re-installing ruby and rubygems.